# Folland 2.22 absolute value of Lebesgue integral less than integral of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have been learning real analysis but I am a bit shaky with complex numbers. In the following proposition, Folland writes $|\int f|=\overline{\operatorname{sgn}(\int f)}\int f$? Why is this true and what is the motivation for doing this? I understand that in the real numbers, $x=\operatorname{sgn}(x)|x|$? I could understand then getting $|x|=\frac{1}{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}x$. However why does the above hold in the complex numbers using modulus instead of absolute value?

EDIT: One more question, why is it that $\int \alpha f$ is real?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition $\operatorname{sgn}(z) = z/|z|$ is a unit vector. As such, $|z| = z/\operatorname{sgn}(z) = \overline{\operatorname{sgn}(z)} * z$.

This is because for any unit vector $u \in \mathbb{C}$, we have $1/u = \overline{u}$.

Comment: Thanks! This makes so much sense. Why is it though that $\int \alpha f $ is real?

Comment: You're welcome! It is because $|\int f| = \alpha * \int f = \int  \alpha f$ using linearity of the integral, and the modulus of any complex number is real.